# Under what circumstances is a non-uniform quantizer preferable over a uniform quantizer?

Tags: digital-communications, homework

> I am studying btech ECE 3rd year. I want answer that question. Please tell me.

Comment: One name sounds better. I'm sorry, questions of the type "what is better about A compared to B" **always** are unclear unless you deliver the metric under which one compares. And, *most of the time*, thinking about what could serve as metric solves such questions.

Answer (score 2):

assuming the number of bits in the quantizer output word is the same for both uniform and non-uniform quantizer, then the number of quantization levels is the same for both.  then it is just a matter of placement of the quantization levels.

the *"noise"* or error of quantization is the difference between the quantized signal (the output) and the unquantized input.  the error will be proportional to the spacing of the quantization levels.  levels that are more closely spaces will have smaller quantization error than where levels that are spaced further apart.

let's assume the number of bits and the number of quantization levels are constant.

a uniform quantizer has uniformly-spaced quantization levels throughout the range.  large signals have the same spacing of quantization levels as do smaller signals.  that means that the smaller signals will have a lower signal-to-noise ratio (SNR).

a non-uniform quantizer can be designed so that the quantization levels are spaced more closely for smaller amplitudes and spaced more far apart for larger amplitudes.  as a result the signal-to-noise ratio can be made constant for both small signals and for large signals.  the SNR of the non-uniform quantizer would be **worse** than the uniform for large signals, but would be **better** than the uniform quantizer for small signals.

Answer (score 1):

A nonuniform (pdf optimized) quantizer produces a smaller MSQE (mean squared quantization error) compared to a uniform one at the same number of distinct output levels; i.e., at the same bitrate.

Note that for this to happen the actual input PDF (probability density function) should **match** the PDF that's used in designing the pdf optimized quantizer, otherwise the expected benefit might even turn into a flaw when there is a mismatch.

Therefore a uniform quantizer fundamentally has the disadvantage of producing more average quantization error at the same bitrate, when compared to a pdf-optimized nonuniform quantizer.

The disadvantage, however, is minimal at high bitrates (more number of bits per sample) and the gain from its design simplicity outweighs the loss from accuracy hence the uniform quantizers are preferred for high bitrate applications. This is especially true when the quantization is not used for signal **compression** but for digitization (ADC) purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In Signal Detection Theory, when the noise is not Gaussian, non uniform quantization is used.  A fairly advanced treatment is given in:

Kassam, Saleem A. Signal detection in non-Gaussian noise. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

The original book is around 1989.  Kassam has a number of IEEE papers on the topic, and since you are a student, both the book and papers are probably available. If you have access to IEEE Xplore, you can check the citations of his articles for the most up to date results.

A really simple example, is for heavy tailed impulsive noise, a clipper is useful.  A real world example is SONAR processing under hard pack ice.

Another useful reference is:

S. A. Kassam and H. V. Poor, "Robust techniques for signal processing: A survey," in Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 73, no. 3, pp. 433-481, March 1985.
doi: 10.1109/PROC.1985.13167
keywords: {Additive noise;Gaussian noise;Minimax techniques;Nonlinear filters;Radar signal processing;Robustness;Signal design;Signal detection;Signal processing;Working environment noise},
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1457435&isnumber=31347